# Is there Terraform to create the "Repository for sensitive data discovery results" for AWS Macie?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-macie

When you manually create an AWS Macie account in the AWS dashboard, and then a Macie job, you afterwards see an alert to "Configure an S3 bucket for long-term retention of your sensitive data discovery results".

You can configure this in the AWS dashboard (see image).

How can I configure this bucket and link it to Macie in Terraform?

I do not see anything in the Macie Terraform resources to do this.

[image: AWS Macie image]

I set up Macie in Terraform with the following and afterwards it still asks me in the AWS dashboard to set the above up :

```
resource "aws_macie2_account" "example" {
  finding_publishing_frequency = "SIX_HOURS"
  status                       = "ENABLED"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.example_bucket]
}

# Get the current caller identity
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_macie2_classification_job" "example_job" {
  job_type       = "SCHEDULED" # or "SCHEDULED" for periodic scans
  name           = "example-macie-job-scheduled-2"
  schedule_frequency {
    daily_schedule = true # Or use weekly_schedule or monthly_schedule
  }
  s3_job_definition {
    bucket_definitions {
      account_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
      buckets    = [aws_s3_bucket.macie_results_bucket.bucket]
    }
  }
  sampling_percentage = 100 
  depends_on = [aws_macie2_account.example]
  # Specify where to store the results
  custom_data_identifier_ids = []
  initial_run                = true
}
```

After I apply the above Terraform and go into the AWS Macie dashboard I see the below message. How can I configure this in Terraform?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See `discovery_result` in the following macie-account terraform [submodule page](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/tedilabs/security/aws/latest/submodules/macie-account#input_discovery_result) and [input description page](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/tedilabs/security/aws/latest/submodules/macie-account?tab=inputs).

It's `null` as default and optional, so you will want to see the example from this `main.tf` of the [Macie-account module](https://github.com/tedilabs/terraform-aws-security/blob/1603cf0fbc809d3ef5a14acf92b8889f05380de3/modules/macie-account/main.tf#L83) how to use the option.